# RabbitMQ has non-visible queues messages

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

For the past couple days my RMQ server has been accumulating messages that never get cleared from the queue. I'm using RMQ as a celery task broker, and the messages are accumulating in the main celery worker queue:

[image]

The queue intermittently switches to an active state when tasks are piped in, processes them, and then goes idle again. Those 21 messages, however, are there permanently. When I click through to the `celery` queue UI and try to look up these messages for inspection, I'm told that my queue is empty:

[image]

I've tried inspecting the messages via the URL endpoint `https://<user>:<password>@<host url>/api/queues/%2f/celery`. I can see in the `message_stats` section that there are 21 messages, but I can't inspect the messages individually:

```
 'message_stats': {'ack': 274597,
  'ack_details': {'rate': 0.0},
  'deliver': 274634,
  'deliver_details': {'rate': 0.0},
  'deliver_get': 274634,
  'deliver_get_details': {'rate': 0.0},
  'deliver_no_ack': 0,
  'deliver_no_ack_details': {'rate': 0.0},
  'get': 0,
  'get_details': {'rate': 0.0},
  'get_empty': 0,
  'get_empty_details': {'rate': 0.0},
  'get_no_ack': 0,
  'get_no_ack_details': {'rate': 0.0},
  'publish': 274618,
  'publish_details': {'rate': 0.0},
  'redeliver': 16,
  'redeliver_details': {'rate': 0.0}},
 'messages': 21,
 'messages_details': {'rate': 0.0},
```

I have two questions:

1. Are there any other RMQ API endpoints that I should be using for individual-level message inspection? I'm trying to avoid firing up a flower server just for debugging purposes.
2. Are there any obvious reasons why these 21 tasks are not inspectable via the UI, or why they seem to just idly accumulate in this queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those remaining messages were are `unacked`, which means that they were sent to some consumer that has yet to acknowledge them.

If you manually close the queue connections or the consumers that have failed to acknowledge them from the management UI, they should revert to the `ready` state and be ready to be consumed again.

Comment: One more question about this: how can I identify the consumers that hace failed to acknowledge the `unacked` messages?

Comment: @aaron in the management UI, if you go to the queue's channels (a client could create several channels), you have the "Messages unacknowledged" stat